# VIM: Use python 2.5 with vim 7.2

Tags: python, vim

How can use Python2.5 with to write scripts in vim? I'm using vim 7.2 and have Python 2.5.  Vim 7.2 seem to be linked with Python 2.4
Do I have to compile from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.gooli.org/blog/gvim-72-with-python-2526-support-windows-binaries/) is a link to VIM 7.2 builds with Python 2.5/2.6 support.